# tensorflow: How to feed numpy.ndarray?

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, type-conversion, tensorflow

I decoded a JPEG image and have it in the shape `n_samples` x `n_features` as a two-dimensional `numpy.ndarray`. I feed this to tensorflow as following:

```
sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={X : train_set.Features, y_ : train_set.labels})
```

This returns a TypeError: `TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'`.

I think it is a simple issue, but I cannot find good advise on that. Closest I found was this post on stack overflow but as far as I understand, that's what I do.

Comment: Can you show us the X, train_set.Features, y_,  train_set.labels (and their shapes)? Some of them probably have the wrong shape.

Comment: Probably your `X` or `y_` is a numpy array, but it should be `tf.Tensor` or `str` containing name of endpoint

Answer (score 1):

I guess your X and train_set.Features maybe have different shape.
for examples,

```
# cifar10 datasets 
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape = (None,32,32,3))
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape = (None,10))
print x_batch.shape   # (batch_size,32,32,3)
print y_batch.shape   # (batch_size,10)
# and feed_dict should be
feed_dict = {x:x_batch,y:y_batch}
```