# How to load torch pretrained models in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, deep-learning, torch, pytorch

I have a torch .t7 file of a binarized pretrained model of the AlexNet. I need to convert this .t7 file to a npz/h5 file so I can import it comfortably.

It is the alexnet_XNOR by allenAI.

This is the code being used to read the file: https://github.com/bshillingford/python-torchfile/blob/master/torchfile.py

```
import torchfile as T
o = T.load('alexnet_XNOR.t7')
```

This is the error that shows up:

```
File "<ipython-input-5-7ef550de1de7>", line 1, in <module>
runfile('C:/Users/yash/Desktop/importer.py', wdir='C:/Users/yash/Desktop')

File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 866, in runfile
execfile(filename, namespace)

File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

File "C:/Users/yash/Desktop/importer.py", line 10, in <module>
o = T.load('alexnet_XNOR.t7')

File "C:\Users\yash\Desktop\torchreader.py", line 430, in load
return reader.read_obj()

File "C:\Users\yash\Desktop\torchreader.py", line 377, in read_obj
obj._obj = self.read_obj()

File "C:\Users\yash\Desktop\torchreader.py", line 394, in read_obj
obj[k] = v

TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'
```

My attempt:
I modified the torchreader and ran the main code (added print statements):

```
for _ in range(size):
            k = self.read_obj()
            v = self.read_obj()
            print(obj.shape)
            print(v.shape)
            obj[k] = v
            if self.use_list_heuristic:
                if not isinstance(k, int) or k <= 0:
                    keys_natural = False
                elif isinstance(k, int):
                    key_sum += k
```

It said None for obj.shape, and for v.shape, it said:

### AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'shape'

```
print(obj)
print("===========")
print(v)
```

When i simply print obj and v using the above snippet code, I get this followed by simply the error i got initially:

```
{}
=================
b'torch.CudaTensor'
{b'_type': b'torch.CudaTensor'}
=================
[]
{b'output': array([], dtype=float32), b'_type': b'torch.CudaTensor'}
=================
b'gradInput'
{None: b'gradInput', b'output': array([], dtype=float32), b'_type': b'torch.CudaTensor'}
=================
[ 0.]
```

Can someone explain why this error is happening? I cannot understand the codebase itself as I have not worked with torch before.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you post error log here ?

Comment: Sorry but I think that I have already given the error log, isnt it?

Comment: You can look into https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36946802/tensorflow-how-to-feed-numpy-ndarray this post

Comment: That didn't help much. I have added some information, please let me know if you can help here